# Performing two actions with one form in django

Tags: python, django

Here I am trying to perform two actions deleting or sending email to selected users.For sending emails a form will be required so I stored checked users in a session like this and after sending email i am removing all the users from session with `session['users'].clear()`.It says sub and msg is required even if I provided .
 What's wrong with this code?

Deleting the selected users working fine

```
def selected_users(request):
    form = SendMailForm()
    selected_users = get_user_model().objects.filter(id__in=request.POST.getlist('users'))
    initial = {'users':[]}
    session = request.session.get('users',initial)
    if selected_users:
        for user in selected_users:
            if not user in session['users']:
                session['users'].append(user.email)
    print('hello1',session['users'])
    if selected_users and  request.method == 'POST' and 'delete_selected' in request.POST:
            count = selected_users.count()
            selected_users.delete()
            messages.success(request, '{} users deleted.'.format(count))
            return redirect('view_users')
    elif request.method == 'POST' and 'mail_selected' in request.POST:
            form = SendMailForm(request.POST or None)
            config = EmailConfiguration.objects.order_by('-date').first()
            backend = EmailBackend(host=config.email_host, port=config.email_port, username=config.email_host_user,
                                   password=config.email_host_password, use_tls=config.email_use_tls)
            if form.is_valid():
                sub = form.cleaned_data['sub']
                msg = form.cleaned_data['msg']
                for email in session['users']:
                    email = EmailMessage(subject=sub, body=msg, from_email=config.email_host_user, to=[email],
                                             connection=backend)

                    email.send()
                    # clearing users from session after email sends
                    session['users'].clear()
                    messages.success(request, 'Your mail sent.')
                    return redirect('view_users')
            else:
                print(form.errors)

    return render(request, 'send_mail_selected.html', {'users': selected_users,'form':form,'session':session})
```

forms.py

```
class SendMailForm(forms.Form):
    #to = forms.EmailField(required=False)
    sub = forms.CharField(max_length=250)
    msg = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

template

```
 <form  method="POST" >
  {% csrf_token %                               

{{form.as_p}}
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="mail_selected">Send </button>

</form>
```

Comment: Probably you should use `exists()` to check if there is any user exists in `selected_users`. IE: `if selected_users.exists():`

Comment: @ruddra  It says sub and msg is required

Comment: I guess you are seeing it form.errors. Please share your html  and form code

Comment: @ruddra yes it is .updated my ques